# Is there any way to search for contacts with special characters using other characters in the CiviCRM search?

Tags: search

E.g. ss = ß, ae = ä, ue = ü, oe = ö

Our language is German but English-speaking colleagues should be able to search for German contacts without having to copy a character from the character table. In addition, as native speakers, we sometimes don't know whether a surname is spelled with ß or ss. We then always have to look for both variants.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL wildcards in most search fields.  Using a percentage sign will find either character - e.g. `G%nther` will find `Gunther`, `Günther`, and `Guenther`.  Note that this slows down searches, especially if it's at the very front of the search.

Answer (score 0):

Also in case of the German "Umlaute" you should be able to simply type a/o/u instead of ä/ö/ü in most searches. Searching for "Jurgen" would for example also yield all "Jürgen" in the database.

Afaik, a coherent phonetic search does not exist for CiviCRM yet.